# Codename One iOS build error with javax_annotation_Resource, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: ios, nullpointerexception, annotations, codenameone

We build iOS through codename one build server but always reply below error, however, it is successful and the application is well for android build.

Please advice what the error meaning and solution. We are wondering if it is about the native interface which cannot not be loaded, if so, please tell how to reload them?

Thanks and Regards,

Ronald Chan

> Error while working with the class: javax_annotation_Resource
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeClass.fillVirtualMethodTable(ByteCodeClass.java:1295)
>     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeClass.fillVirtualMethodTable(ByteCodeClass.java:1286)
>     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeClass.updateAllDependencies(ByteCodeClass.java:226)
>     at com.codename1.tools.translator.Parser.writeOutput(Parser.java:387)
>     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.main(ByteCodeTranslator.java:205)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeClass.fillVirtualMethodTable(ByteCodeClass.java:1295)
>     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeClass.fillVirtualMethodTable(ByteCodeClass.java:1286)
>     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeClass.updateAllDependencies(ByteCodeClass.java:226)
>     at com.codename1.tools.translator.Parser.writeOutput(Parser.java:387)
>     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.main(ByteCodeTranslator.java:205)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `javax.annotation.Resource` e.g. `@Resource`.

You compiled that code without [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) or changed the classpath which results in our servers getting code that they don't support.